# How to use ng-content within a directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

How can I use angular `@Directive` to create custom button element like angular does with their `mat-button`?

Let say, I'm writing

```html
<button mat-button>Basic</button>
```

And angular display it like this

```html
<button mat-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-button mat-button-base">
  <span class="mat-button-wrapper">Basic</span>
</button>
```

How could I do this with ?

```html
<button custom-button>Basic</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular material uses `@Component` with `mat-button`, as (one of the many) selector is `button[mat-button]`. So it's a component, not a directive (although a component extends directive, but you get the point)

You can check [here](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.ts) how they did that.

This is part of the template they use:

```
<span class="mat-button-wrapper"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
```